# Linux device using network manager fails to connect to the network manager AP with a hidden SSID

Tags: wireless-access-point, networkmanager

I created an access point using the network manager with the hidden SSID and it works fine if I want to use it with my android phone, but then trying to connect to the access point using Linux device (using network manager) it asks for the password again and again even though it is 100% correct.

I have tried:

- `nmcli dev wifi connect "$SSID" password "$password" hidden yes`
- creating the connection manually and configuring everything before activating it
- using this tool `https://github.com/kokoye2007/wifi-qr` and scanning the QR code provided by the network manager running on the access point machine (on the android device I connected to the network using the same QR code)

Comment: Since different versions of Linux may react differently to a hidden SSID (not really hidden at all), try this thread.     .......  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368964/connect-to-my-hidden-wifi-which-i-know-the-password-and-the-ssid-name

Comment: @John thanks for your help, I got it working with wpa_supplicant, though it is still interesting why using network manager doesn't work